# XCode Not Showing where Compiler Errors Exist

Tags: xcode

All of a sudden, XCode has stopped showing me which lines the compiler is complaining about. Here is a screenshot where I've intentionally created a syntax error. See how the Issue Navigator points out that there is an error in ViewController.m. I know that the error is on line 147 (because I forced it there), but notice that there is no information next to that line at all. Anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: I know it may sound trite, but try quitting and re-launching Xcode

Comment: First rule of tech support, right? Didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Another trite idea: clean and rebuild

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Why I didn't think of that, I'll never know, but no matter.